# How to allow Only numbers in Outlook VBA input box

Tags: vba, outlook

I am writing a macro where user is asked to input a number. But i am unable validate whether input is number or not. I am trying Type:=1, but it gives an error. Here is my piece of code.

```
Limit = Replace(Trim(Left(Split(b, "LIMIT:")(1), 
        Len(Split(b, "LIMIT:")(1)) - 
        Len(Split(b, "EXCESS:")(1)) - 7)), ".", "")
If Limit = "Up to full value any one Occurrence and in all 
            during the Period" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf Then
Limit = TIV
Else
Limit = InputBox(prompt:="Limit is not FULL VALUE. Enter Limit",
        Title:="LIMIT", Default:=TIV,Type:=1)
End If
MsgBox Limit
```

Please suggest what should be the solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub getLimit()
    Dim Limit As Variant
    Do While True
        Limit = InputBox("please enter a number", "LIMIT")
        If IsNumeric(Limit) Then
            MsgBox Limit, , "LIMIT"
            Exit Do
        End If
        If MsgBox("Limit is not FULL VALUE. Enter Limit", vbOKCancel, "LIMIT") = vbCancel Then Exit Do
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: you can put the _Limit = InputBox ...._ line inside the _do while_ loop, then you do not have to repeat it at end of the loop

Comment: @curious thank you. It is working. I have optimized it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Application.InputBox` for the Type to work.

An alternative is to use a userform containing a textbox and add this code to the `Change()` event of the textbox:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    With Me.TextBox1
        If .Text Like "[!0-9]" Or Val(.Text) < -1 Or .Text Like "?*[!0-9]*" Then
            Beep
            .Text = Left(.Text, Len(.Text) - 1)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

As soon as you type a character it checks what it is - if it's not a number then it removes it.

Answer (score 0):

As Darren mentioned `Application.InputBox` will save you

```
Function Limit() as Double
    Limit = Application.InputBox("Please insert Limit", "Limit", , , , , , 1)
End Function
```

You can type anything into inputbox but it will not close until your input value is a number